# Telerik ticker tags not working in Razor Views ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, telerik, ticker

I have gone through some Telerik Ticker's demos On these pages - [demo1](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ticker/examples/functionality/radticker/defaultcs.aspx) , [demo2](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/rotator/examples/multiplescroller/defaultcs.aspx) and [demo3](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ticker/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) . These demos do not include their code for Razor (cshtml) Views and if I skip all the ASP.NET Tags and only choose Telerik Tags Like below in my razor views it does not show any output

```
<telerik:RadTicker ID="RadTicker1" AutoStart="true" Width="300px">
    <items>
        <telerik:RadTickerItem ID="RadTickerItem1" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.">
        </telerik:RadTickerItem>
    </items>
</telerik:RadTicker>
```

It does not work in Razor . Any reason , solution or alternative will be appreciatable .


**Note**

code of aspx pages is included in the demos linked in the question .I'm working on VS2013 mvc5

Answer (score 0):

`<telerik:RadTicker>` will only work for web forms because it will need a designer.cs code. It is not design for you to use in MVC razor views. cshtml can only accept HTML elements combined with Razor commands, no ASP.NET controls.

Comment: how can you say that . Have some reference to Telerik Official notification . If you have kindly share that

Comment: In MVC view, can you add `<asp:Label />`?

Comment: kindly read the question carefully , i'm not asking about asp label tag . I want telerik rad ticker to work in Razor Views

Comment: I was just doing a comparison for you to clearly understand. I'm just saying that webforms like `<asp:Label />` don't work with Views. Similar to `<telerik:RadTicker>` because that is also a webform. What you can do is see if telerik has a JavaScript you can utilize go attain the same goal as `<telerik:RadTicker>`